# Video Call and Voice Plugin for Education Website

Tags: video, call, moodle

I am making a Moodle project. It's that teachers joins and students can self learn. This was done.

But for a Live Classroom/Chat with Video support which enables students learn live with teacher what should preferred to do.

I had known userplane but it is now been closed. Know CometChat its a bit great but extremely expensive.

Any other ideas or providers of video chat service. Even is thier any scripts for self hosted but less than $300.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Bigbluebutton](http://bigbluebutton.org/) is an opensource solution and has been [integrated in Moodle](http://bigbluebutton.org/).

You can view some [demos here](https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=set&id=2). [image: A screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use WizIQ as a Virtual Classroom module for Moodle users. For details please refer this:
http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/wiziq_live_class_module

Hope this helps